# Нужно с помощью jQuery из таблицы получить значение одного из полей

Tags: javascript, jquery

Встал вопрос, что со страницы с таблицами нужно собрать данные, но у меня не получается к ним обратиться, потому что мало знаний, уже несколько дней ищу информацию, решил задать вопрос.
Условно есть alert, на который должны эти данные повториться со страницы, вот пример моего кода, при alert вылазит окно без значений:

Пытался и так

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("#table-body > tr:nth-child(1) > td.copy-name > Скопировать ").values()
alert(elements)
```

И так:

```
var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("#table-body > tr:nth-child(1) > td.copy-name > Скопировать").values())
alert(elements)
```

Я отрезал кусок от изначальной страницы, с которой мне и надо вытянуть значение, получилось вот что:

```
<tbody id="table-body" class=""><tr data-item-id="32897" data-pos="1649"><td class="copy-name" title="Скопировать">ЭТОТ ТЕКСТ</td></tr></tbody>
```

Мне нужно просто загнать хоть в какую переменную или в alert **ЭТОТ ТЕКСТ** , мучаюсь уже 3 дня, но ничего путного не выходит.

Если кто-то решится мне помочь и чего-то будет не хватать для решения вопроса, я скину все что нужно, просто я не знаю какие данные нужно еще давать.

Comment: только не value а как минимум textContent или innerHTML

Comment: Я не вижу `jquery`

Comment: Попробуйте `alert(document.querySelector("#table-body td.copy-name").textContent)`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko А не подскажете как мне подсчитать количество строк в таблице? Просто их количество будет постоянно изменяться, а мне нужно знать их количество, или допустим считать до момента, пока эти строки не закончатся они будут вида вот такого
<tbody id="table-body" class=""> <tr data-item-id="32897" data-pos="1649"><td class="copy-name" title="Скопировать">ЭТОТ ТЕКСТ1</td></tr> <tr data-item-id="328327" data-pos="1239"><td class="copy-name" title="Скопировать">ЭТОТ ТЕКСТ2</td></tr> 
Здесь только 2, но будет допустим от 1 до 40. Если здесь не удобно, можете ответить ответом.

Comment: Не понятно, чего вы хотите. Не надо нам показывать слона по кусочкам. Внятно и детально опишите вашу задачу, что вы хотите сделать. Потом опишите, что не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перебираем все td и при click копируем (можно проверить вставив в текстовый документ) и выводим `alert` о том что скопированно

Я тыкал на td и результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
document.querySelectorAll("td").forEach(function(item) {
  item.onclick = function() {
    document.execCommand("copy");
  }
  item.addEventListener("copy", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.clipboardData) {
      event.clipboardData.setData("text/plain", item.textContent);
      alert("скопировано");
    }
  });
})
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
    <td>kato</td>
    <td>sheboigen</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>alert</td>
    <td>kraus</td>
    <td>12.04.202</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>stenly</td>
    <td>10,20</td>
    <td>barny18</td>
    <td>rool</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```